# square matrix depending on complex value: spectral radius continous?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues, spectral-radius

Let $A(z)$ be a $n\times n$ square matrix depending on the complex value $z$ and $\lambda_z$ is its spectral radius.

Is $\lambda_z$ continous or is it possible that it can jump? Or maybe someone knows a good example for that?

**Comment:** $A(z)$ consists of complex functions $a_{ij}(z)$ and the spectral radius is defined as
$$
\lambda_z=\max\{|\lambda|:\text{ $\lambda$  is an eigenvalue of $A(z)$}\}.
$$

Comment: How do you define the largest eigenvalue $\lambda\in\mathbb C$?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the answers to your questions!

Comment: certainly not; for a simple counter example, take the $2\times 2 $ diagonal matrix with $iz$ and $z^2$ on the diagonal; as $z$ moves along the real axis and crosses 1 the "largest" eigenvalue jumps from $i$ to 1.

Comment: Thank you for the example, i will check that. Is the assertion true if we would take real values instead of complex?

Comment: a counter example with real matrix elements: $2\times 2$ diagonal matrix with $-x$ and $x^2$ on the diagonal, the eigenvalue with the largest absolute value jumps from $-1$ to $1$ when $x$ crosses 1.

Comment: Thank you. Your examples are diagonal matrices: What if we would take just positive matrices? Lets say $A(z)\geq 0$.

Comment: the eigenvalues themselves depend continuously on the matrix elements, so if all eigenvalues are positive taking the absolute value makes no difference and the largest eigenvalue will depend continuously on the matrix elements.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker : Your counterexamples are based on your misunderstanding of the question. The "largest eigenvalue" $\lambda_z$ is defined (somewhat awkwardly) in the OP as the largest modulus of the eigenvalues, not as an eigenvalue with the largest modulus.

Comment: I don’t understand the difference. I am interested in the spectral radius of $A(z)$, that is the maximum of the absolute values of its eigenvalues.

Comment: @Fynn13 : In general, the spectral radius is not the same as the largest eigenvalue. In fact, if (say) all eigenvalues are complex (but not real) numbers, then a largest eigenvalue does not exist. Also, the spectral radius $\lambda_z$ is the largest modulus of the eigenvalues, not an eigenvalue with the largest modulus. In particular, an eigenvalue with the largest modulus can be a complex number that is not real, whereas the spectral radius is always a (nonnegative) real number. I have edited your post accordingly.

Comment: Okey, I'm a little confused. So in my case (the spectral radius), the counter examples above are correct or your text below?

Comment: @Fynn13 : What is confusing here for you? As I said, the counterexamples above are not about the spectral radius; they are about an eigenvalue with the largest modulus. On the other hand, I believe my answer is correct.

Comment: Do you have a further response to the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\la\lambda$If (all the entries $a_{ij}(z)$ of) the matrix $A(z)$ are continuous in $z$, then, yes, $\la_z$ is continuous in $z$.

Indeed, take any complex $z$ and any sequence $(z_k)$ converging to $z$. Then, according to (say) [Sections 5.1 and 5.2 of Chapter II](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-66282-9), the set of eigenvalues of $A(z_k)$ converges to the set of eigenvalues of $A(z)$ in the following sense: for some enumeration $(\la_1(z),\dots,\la_n(z))$ of the eigenvalues of $A(z)$ and some enumerations $(\la_1(z_k),\dots,\la_1(z_k))$ of the eigenvalues of $A(z_k)$ one has
$$\max(|\la_1(z_k)-\la_1(z)|,\dots,|\la_n(z_k)-\la_n(z)|)\to0$$
(as $k\to\infty$). It follows that
$$\la_{z_k}=\max(|\la_1(z_k)|,\dots,|\la_n(z_k)|)
\to\max(|\la_1(z)|,\dots,|\la_n(z)|)=\la_z.\quad\Box$$

---

Clearly, the condition that $A(z)$ be continuous in $z$ cannot be dropped. For example, consider the case when $a_{11}(z)$ is not continuous in $z$ whereas $a_{ij}(z)=0$ for all $z$ if $(i,j)\ne(1,1)$.

Comment: By Gelfand's formula, the spectral radius can be computed as the limit of operator norms of the powers of the matrix, but I don't see immediately how to derive continuity.  There should be a simpler argument than enumerating *all* the eigenvalues.

Comment: @MikhailKatz : (i) I think the argument is already very simple. (ii) To deal with the maximum of the moduli of all the eigenvalues, we need to deal with all the eigenvalues somehow. Of course, enumerating them is only one way to do that. Alternatively, one can e.g. describe the continuity of the set of eigenvalues the way it is done in Section 5.1 of Chapter II of Kato's book, linked in my answer. (iii) Like you, I don't see a simple (or any other) way to use Gelfand's formula here.

Comment: @MikhailKatz: Using just Gelfand's formula can't do the job since Gelfand's formula also holds in infinite dimensions while contuity of the spectral radius does not.

Comment: @JochenGlueck : This is a good point!